# Test multiple file conditions by combining flags—does it work?

Tags: bash, shell, rhel, solaris, test

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37429106/3892044) over at StackOverflow, which received at least two upvotes, is what worked on the shell of a workstation I used at my previous workplace. On that workstation, which is probably some old version of SunOS or Red Hat Commercial Linux or Red Hat Enterprise Linux, `[[ -fwd`*`path`*`]]` tests the existence of *`path`* as both a regular file and a writable directory. `sh`, `bash`, `csh`, `tcsh` and `zsh` were the only possible shells installed on that workstation, and I most likely ran it in `bash`.

I'm asking this question because I was not able to reproduce that now on other Unix-like operating systems. It always gives me a *syntax error*, so I'm starting to doubt if I ever ran it successfully.

My question is: on what systems is this code valid, and if so, is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Which bash version do you use on SunOS and RHEL?

Comment: Not valid on bash `version 4.3.30(1)-release (i386-pc-solaris2.11)`.  I get syntax error as well if I try multiple file test operators.

Comment: @Cyrus No clue, but if it's SunOS, it's either one of the SunOS 4.x versions or SunOS 5.10, so probably bash 1 or 2, and maybe installed in the xpg4 directory?

Comment: @Cyrus I remember seeing a ucb directory on some of the workstations, too, so bash could also be installed there, or just plain old `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. It might also have been SunOS 5.11... Sorry my memory is hazy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that doesn't work. Not really in any version of bash.

This test works in any bash version (in fact, in any shell):

```
$ [ -fwd ] && echo "It worked" || echo "not"
It worked
```

But what it is testing is not a file flag, it is testing whether the string `-fwd` is of length 0 or not. As it has some characters, the test is true.

Using `[[` change which flags are allowed:

```
$ [[ -fwd  ]] && echo "It worked" || echo "not"
b204sh          : /home/user/so: line 3: unexpected argument to conditional unary operator
```

Gives the above error in bash up to bash 3.2.
There is no error for bash versions after 3.2, but the result is truthful:

```
$ [[ -fwd ]] && echo "It worked" || echo "not"
It worked
```

which is imposible: a directory entry can not be both a file (`-f`) and a directory (`-d`).

This confirms the idea that the test is actually testing the string:

```
$ [[ \-fwd ]] && echo "It worked" || echo "not"
It worked
```

#### Testing with a file

```
$ touch wds
$ [[ -fwd wds ]] && echo "It worked" || echo "not"
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `wds'
```

Gives a fail message on bash versions after 3.2.
For other versions it gives a truthful answer (which is imposible for file tests, a directory entry could not be at the same time a file and a directory).

Comparing this two tests, it seems that only the first letter is used:

```
$ b204sh -c '[[ -fd wds ]] && echo "It worked" || echo "not"'
It worked

$ b204sh -c '[[ -df wds ]] && echo "It worked" || echo "not"'
not
```

Likely a bug corrected on bash 4

Fails also in:

[csh](/questions/tagged/csh) `[[: No match.`
[tcsh](/questions/tagged/tcsh) `[[: Command not found.`
[zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) `unknown condition: -fd` # Version 5.4.2
[ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) `syntax error at line 3:`wds' unexpected` # Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01

Comment: You're saying `[[ -fwd wds ]]` gives a truthful answer on bash versions prior to version 3.2?

Comment: @Gao Yes, in bash 2.04, 2.05, 3.0 and 3.2 (the versions tested).

Comment: Could you please try `[[ -rwx file ]]` and observe the return status for each bit mask (1, 2, 4 is enough)? I vaguely remember (though I could be wrong) that it's not just the first letter that is used. I also think it's a bug because `shopt -s compat31 # or compat32` on bash 4.4.12(1)-release doesn't reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @Gao `b204sh -c '[[ -rx wds ]] ; echo "$?"'` outputs `0`, however `b204sh -c '[[ -xr wds ]] ; echo "$?"'` outputs `1`. That is a clear conflict with the theory that all flags are tested. That doesn't work.